# Obtain CiteScore rank

Tags: bibliometrics, scopus

Is possible to obtain the information about the CiteScore rank for a journal?

I have seen in "Elsevier Developers" that there are different APIs to obtain the SJR and SNIP metrics, but nothing about CiteScore rank and I need to obtain the percentile in a given year.

Comment: What do you want to do with that?

Comment: I have a set of articles published in different journals indexed by Scopus and Scimago. So I need to take the quartiles in which those journals have been classified over the years, in order to know the classification that the articles will have. 
So I wanted to know if it was possible to get the quartiles (percentiles in the case of scopus) through an API. Since due to the large volume of information it is very tedious to do it manually

Answer (score 1):

Scopus gives a list here. Is it what you are interested in:

https://journalmetrics.scopus.com/